Repeating Notification from Firebase Massaging
We have a Flutter app and we need to send a repetitive notification with same content to our users.
I have create a notification from Firebase Messaging console which is supposed to send a notification twice a week on Sunday and Wednesday.


We are receiving the notifications normally for 1 or 2 weeks and then it stops completely.
When I delete the notification and create a new one with exact properties then it will start working also fine for 1 or 2 weeks max and it stops again.
What could be the reason? Is there any type of limitations since Firebase Messaging is free of charge?

Have you already tried changing the "subject to frequency limit" and set it to max 1 per day? Just to check if is that which limits you?

I have edited the Task now and changed it to "Subject to frequency limit " with 1 day limit but when checking it again it is set to 7 days and cannot be changed to less - I guess this is because my notification is set to once a week (7 days). I will check if it works this time and I will let your know. Thank you
